# Resolving Stack Linker Error

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

What's the meaning of this stack output error?

```
$stack build -v
...
2017-06-16 07:59:19.792336: [info] Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/my-project/my-project ...
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.457898: [warn] Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.458019: [warn]   "_iconv", referenced from:
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.483052: [warn]       _hs_iconv in libHSbase-4.9.1.0.a(iconv.o)
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.558523: [warn]      (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv, _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding5_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding10_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncodingzuloc_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncodingzuloc1_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding7_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding4_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding11_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding8_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding11_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding2_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding2_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding9_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding9_closure , _hs_iconv_open , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncodingzuloc_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncodingzuloc1_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding3_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding8_info , _hs_iconv_close , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding10_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding7_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding4_closure )
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.558678: [warn]   "_iconv_close", referenced from:
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.584378: [warn]       _hs_iconv_close in libHSbase-4.9.1.0.a(iconv.o)
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.659175: [warn]      (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv_close)
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.659322: [warn]   "_iconv_open", referenced from:
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.684266: [warn]       _hs_iconv_open in libHSbase-4.9.1.0.a(iconv.o)
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.760039: [warn]      (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv_open)
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.760166: [warn]   "_locale_charset", referenced from:
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.774056: [warn]       _localeEncoding in libHSbase-4.9.1.0.a(PrelIOUtils.o)
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.911418: [warn] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.930402: [warn] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.931503: [warn] `gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1070:67)
2017-06-16 07:59:22.961835: [debug] Start: getPackageFiles /Users/kevinmeredith/Workspace/my-project-group/HS/my-project.cabal
@(Stack/Package.hs:251:21)
2017-06-16 07:59:23.011242: [debug] Finished in 49ms: getPackageFiles /Users/kevinmeredith/Workspace/my-project-group/HS/my-project.cabal
@(Stack/Package.hs:251:21)
2017-06-16 07:59:23.016261: [debug] Encoding /Users/kevinmeredith/Workspace/my-project-group/HS/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-build-cache
@(Data/Store/VersionTagged.hs:51:5)
2017-06-16 07:59:23.017031: [debug] Finished writing /Users/kevinmeredith/Workspace/my-project-group/HS/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/stack-build-cache
@(Data/Store/VersionTagged.hs:55:5)
```

Also, how can I fix it?

Comment: can you show us the error without `-v` ? I suspect you're talking about the linker errors but I want to be sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the paths `/Users/` I guess you are using MacOS.

Looking at

https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/issues/74

it seems like the code is compiled against the header file of
one version of libiconv and linked against another incompatible version
of libiconv.

you could probably try the solution suggested there and add the ghc option

```
--extra-lib-dirs=/usr/lib
```

Also take a look at

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4068